# Agricultural imaging and optical filters

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I am looking into different cameras or sensors that i could use to measure the following em ranges that are useful to agriculture. I'm hoping to construct an open source device(s) to measure the following within a small and reproducible device(s):

Cellulose Absorption Index: 2000-2200nm

Plant Water Index: 902-970nm

Disease Water Stress Index: 547-1657nm

NDVI 670-800nm

I am also looking for filters or filter combinations for the following ranges:

Cellulose Absorption Index: 2000-2200nm

Plant Water Index: 902-970nm

Disease Water Stress Index: 547-1657nm

Thanks

Comment: This sounds off-topic for this site. You might want to try https://photo.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ThePointer the post was removed from photo exchange for being off topic

Comment: Try electronics.stackexchange. And you should probably add more detail. This website is more-so focused on physics concepts.